# Find the chromatic polynomial of $P_3\times P_n$

Tags: graph-theory, coloring

I understand the concept of the chromatic polynomial of the ladder graph $P_2\times P_n$ but I can not find the chromatic polynomial of $P_3\times P_n$.

Answer (score 1):

I doubt there is any nice formula.  The first few are:
\begin{matrix}
n & \text{chromatic polynomial of $P_3 \times P_n$}\\
\hline
1 &x (x-1)^2 \\
2 &x (x - 1)(x^2 - 3 x + 3)^2 \\
3 &x (x - 1) (x^7 - 11 x^6 + 55 x^5 - 161 x^4 + 298 x^3 - 350 x^2 + 244 x - 79)
\end{matrix}
The first 30 are [here](https://sites.math.rutgers.edu/~zeilberg/tokhniot/oKamaTzviot3).